# Set background color only for the first row in a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, datagrid, smart-device

I'm trying to change the color only for the first color of a DataGrid in a smartDevice project in c#. 
I tried to use the "Paint" event but couldn't figure out if it could solve my issue.
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

This is a testing code

```
private void buttonRed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow row = this.dataSet1.Tables[0].NewRow();
        row[0] = "002";
        row[1] = "E";
        this.dataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
    }
    private void load()
    {

        this.dataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new object[] { "001", "A" });
        this.dataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new object[] { "002", "B" });
        this.dataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new object[] { "001", "C" });
        this.dataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new object[] { "003", "D" });
    }
    private void buttonGreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow row = this.dataSet1.Tables[0].NewRow();
        row[0] = "004";
        row[1] = "F";
        this.dataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
    }
```

Comment: show us some code we don't know what happen in your smartDevice project

Comment: I've got a DataSet binded to the DataGrid with these columns: "BOX", "NAME". (with some rows ex: "001", "A"; "002", "B"; "001", "C") I would like, when i add a row (on top) to mark that row in red if alredy exist a row with the same bow, otherwise in gree

Comment: Please post your code here rather than describing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Azure;
```

Just do this will work...
0 means the first row.

Comment: I don't have any dataGridView, maybe i'm doing something wrong but on smartDevice projects i've never found it