# set 1st row of datagrid to a different color

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `Datagrid` where a add items using `grid.Items.Insert(0, row);`
I always want the last row I insert to be displayed first on Grid.
I also want the 1st row to have different color from others. For this purpose I am using `LoadingRow` event :

```
private void dataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
 dataGrid.RowBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.AntiqueWhite);//set all rows to default color
 e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.CornflowerBlue); //set current=>1st row row to BLue                                
}
```

However every row added is getting colored `CornflowerBlue` without previous added rows changed to `AntiqueWhite`.
I am missing something obvious, would really appreciate any guidance.

Comment: May be this link will help you out for coloring issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753299/set-background-color-only-for-the-first-row-in-a-datagrid

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the rows in the datagridview and then compare values of columns 7 and 10 on each row (example columns).

Try this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in vendorsDataGridView.Rows) 
 if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[7].Value) < Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[10].Value)) 
 {
     row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Insert instead of Add. This way you can specify where you want to add the new record. To add a new record on top of the grid, just use Insert(0).

DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0) // -- this will add a new record on top, always
DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(n).Value = "abc" // --this will set the value at n column.